# Sort linq query result, when it has "First() and into Group"

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, sorting, sql-order-by

```
var qryLatestInterview = from rows in dt.AsEnumerable()                                     
                         group rows by new 
                         { 
                           PositionID = rows["msbf_acc_cd"], 
                           CandidateID = rows["msbf_fac_tp"] 
                         } into grp
                         select grp.First();
```

I want to sort by above results using `msbf_fac_dt` which is a DateTime Column,

So I did following changes

```
var qryLatestInterview = from rows in dt.AsEnumerable()
                         orderby rows["msbf_fac_dt"] ascending
                         group rows by new 
                         {
                           PositionID = rows["msbf_acc_cd"], 
                           CandidateID = rows["msbf_fac_tp"], 
                           FacilityDate = rows["msbf_fac_dt"] 
                         } into grp
                         select grp.First();
```

But this is not sort by above `msbf_fac_dt` column , what can I do here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can order the group before selecting the first record:

```
var qryLatestInterview = from rows in dt.AsEnumerable()
                         group rows by new
                         {
                             PositionID = rows["msbf_acc_cd"],
                             CandidateID = rows["msbf_fac_tp"],
                         } into grp
                         select grp.OrderBy(x=> x["msbf_fac_dt"]).First();
```

Comment: tried that one also , getting followig `'System.Data.DataRow' does not contain a definition for 'msbf_fac_dt' and no extension method 'msbf_fac_dt' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Data.DataRow' could be found`

Comment: Sorry, already edited my answer while you were writing your comment.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to get recent facilitated record from this list, you could do ordering after grouping and take first record.

```
dt.AsEnumerable()
  .GroupBy(row => new 
   { 
         PositionID = rows["msbf_acc_cd"], 
         CandidateID = rows["msbf_fac_tp"]
   })
  .Select(x=>x.OrderByDescending(o=>o["msbf_fac_dt"]>).FirstOrDefault() 
  .ToList();
```